# Displaying multiple ggplot2 plots one after another in R (like plot.lm does)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

`plot.lm` has a nice feature of displaying plots one after another, so when specifying

```
plot(lm(rnorm(100) ~ rnorm(100, 3, 1)))
```

displays first plot and asks user to

> Hit Return to see next plot:

Now I want to generate 30 plots, so displaying them in a grid will make them hard to read, while specifying them one after another is quite cumbersome. I've been wondering if there is a function or a method to imitate `plot.lm` behaviour? I'm specifically interested in a function that is compatible with `ggplot2`.

Comment: Also note that in most graphics devices you can navigate between plots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Study `stats:::plot.lm`. It uses `devAskNewPage`.

Example:

```
devAskNewPage(TRUE)
for (i in 1:3) plot(i)
devAskNewPage(options("device.ask.default")[[1]])
```

Comment: Or `par(ask = TRUE)`

Comment: `devAskNewPage(options("device.ask.default"))` doesn't seem to work fine (Error in devAskNewPage(options("device.ask.default")) : incorrect argument 'ask'). Is it safe to use something like `devAskNewPage(FALSE)`? Also, should it work ok with `ggplot2`?

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any alternative that works with `ggplot2`?

Comment: @jakes ; what is wrong with this answer as it seems to extend to `ggplot` okay; change the relevant bit of Roland's code to `for (i in 1:3) print(qplot(main=i))`

Comment: @user20650, well, it seems that `print` was necessary here. Could you explain why? What's the diference between `plot` and `qplot` that causes it?

Comment: @jakes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547306/generate-multiple-graphics-from-within-an-r-function ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264324/plot-with-ggplot-in-for-loop-doesnt-work ; https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f